# How to pass one computed variable in multiple activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I just figured out how to use intent to pass variables to other activity ,but I found out that it has a limit , it can only pass one variable to one activity .
I want to know how to share the variable in multiple activity like I have this variable in activity 1 and I want to use it in activity 2 and activity 3.

this is my activity 1 , the variable I want to use in other activity is this 
(double ans=(90+4.8*nh+13.4*nw-5.7*na);) 
I figured out how to pass it to activity 2 but I can't pass it to activity 3. Is there an easy way to pass the variable in multiple activity , because I'm kinda new to Android and OOP there's a lot of stuff I don't really get just from searching. Thank you so much!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_male);

    age =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.age);
    height=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heigth);
    weight =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.weigth);
    result =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    eage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eage);
    eheight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eheight);
    eweight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eweight);


    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    back =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);



    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            double na=Double.parseDouble(eage.getText().toString());
            double nh=Double.parseDouble(eheight.getText().toString());
            double nw=Double.parseDouble(eweight.getText().toString());
            double ans=(90+4.8*nh+13.4*nw-5.7*na);
            result.setText("Your BMR is "+ans);



        }
    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MALE.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MALE.this, MALERUN.class);
            double na=Double.parseDouble(eage.getText().toString());
            double nh=Double.parseDouble(eheight.getText().toString());
            double nw=Double.parseDouble(eweight.getText().toString());
            double ans=(90+4.8*nh+13.4*nw-5.7*na);
            result.setText("Your BMR is "+ans);
            i.putExtra("answer",ans);
            i.putExtra("age",na);
            i.putExtra("height",nh);
            i.putExtra("weight",nw);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: You can use a broadcast receiver to perform this action.

Comment: just pass the stuff in an intent, don't use it as the intent action. Sorry to be so blunt, but go and read the documentation, especially before you start making everything static fields as that makes little sense

Comment: You can store that variable in separate class as static variable .. and then can make changes in this variable throughout your app.. but remember when application restarts the variable will not have value. you need to store variable in shared preferences to achieve this

Comment: I agree with @MuhammadHassaan you can store the value in shared preference and can get back in *OnResume* of activity or fragment whatever you are using.

Comment: How do I use shared preferences ? I have search for this before but I don't know where to put it , and It's quite confusing to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **SharedPreferences** you can get it.here is examples

```
    next.setOnClickListener{

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("answer",ans);
        editor.putString("age",""+na);
        editor.putString("height",""+nh);
        editor.putString("weight",""+nw);
        editor.commit();

        Intent i=new Intent(MALE.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**Any Another Activity you can get it below**

```
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
        String answer = sharedPref.getString("answer",null);
        String age = sharedPref.getString("age",null);
        Log.e("resultsss",""+answer + " age : "+age);

}
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Either you have to use Sqlite database

> **suggestion:** if you have very less fields better to use
>   `SharedPreferences` if you have little hug data better go with Sqlite
>   database

Comment: solution 3, use intents https://www.dev2qa.com/passing-data-between-activities-android-tutorial/

Comment: but what will happen next , I need an intent to switch the activity 1 to 2

Comment: @Y to X yes above example says if you want to get the result from child Activity please look at above exampls

Comment: I tried but there's an error in (this) and editor.putExtra

Comment: @YtoX OMG i am very sry..i will chage it

Comment: @YtoX please check my updated answer....`editor.putExtra` replace into `editor.putString()`

Comment: the change of string work , but there is still something wrong with（this） from SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: @YtoX simple bro..you need pass your context..like(`getDefaultSharedPreferences(MALE.this); `)...so i suggest please learn little more  basic on android

Comment: Ohh , thank you , I'm sorry if I ask something dumb , I am a beginner trying to understand all of this without getting confuse because my teacher in school won't teach this much .

Comment: SharedPreference is not right way to use data across activity, SharedPreference mainly use you want to keep data long time, when app close terminate.

Comment: @YtoX to accepted answer is not the right in your condition. Good Luck

Comment: @YogeshRathi as  a fresher this is easy solution...further  he can learn

Answer (score 1):

Use `SingleTon` Pattern.

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private double yourValue;
    private static SingletonClass sSoleInstance;

    private SingletonClass() {
    } // private constructor.

    public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        if (sSoleInstance == null) { 
            sSoleInstance = new SingletonClass();
        }

        return sSoleInstance;
    }

    public void setValue(double val) {
        yourValue = val;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return yourValue;
    }
    }
```

Set Variable from `Activity1`

```
    SingletonClass.getInstance().setValue(yourValue);
```

Now you can access this value across application.

```
    SingletonClass.getInstance().getValue();
```

For more details [click here](https://medium.com/exploring-code/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0)

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a varible :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Like below
    public static double ans;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
   }
}
```

And call it from everywhere like this:

```
MainActivity.ans;
```

You can declare a different variable anytime you want and it will change in every Activity.

just do this :

```
MainActivity.ans = 123.123;
```

Comment: where should I put it , and wouldn't the variable of ans become 12.123 when it isn't ? because the variable of ans depends on how the computation will do ? or am I wrong?

Comment: why would a static variable be the best solution to pass data between activities? Static fields have all kinds of problems that aren't obvious to beginners until they want to do something more complex. This is really bad advice, no offense

Comment: this is not the professional way. you can store static variable in separate class or or in Shared Preferences. this will not look good in code

Comment: @Arty Your solution is working but its not recommended anywhere, do not try this way in your code also, if your requirement is like above question then try to use SignleTon pattern.